# Sharepoint 2013 custom ribbon localization not working

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, ribbon

I´m trying to localize a custom ribbon group that shows either as contextual group or as a group inside Library default ribbon.

However I cannot get it to localize, it always displays the resource key insted of the localized string.  As you can see below I tried both with Feature resources and Global Resources, without luck:

[image: Contextual Group not being translated]

[image: Group inside Library not being translated]

I did deploy referenced resources (called "Expedientes")  and Feature Resources to their locations, for neutral and en-US cultures:
[image: Resources]
[image: Feature Resources]
When trying to get the resources from code inside a WebPart, everything works fine.

```
this.txtPrueba.Text = SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:Expedientes,Ribbon_TabAccionesDocumentosEntrada", "", (uint)SPContext.Current.Web.UICulture.LCID);
```

this.txtPrueba.Text has the translated text.

Still the Ribbon does not get translated.

What I´m missing?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with SP1, and it worked. Probably a bug that has been fixed